# Magento 2 - production mode Issue

Tags: magento2

I have a strange issue, I have deployed production mode with the command

> bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

it works perfectly, when I take a look at

> bin/magento deploy:mode:show

the result is Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.) which is expected.

But in the backend I see a developer mode behavior :

- Still have "Stores > Advanced > Developer" available (which is mainly not displayed in production mode).
- And in "System > Cache Management" I still have the ability to enable/disable cache.

Files and database was developed in local machine, and I made dump of DB and files to put them in the production server, now I am stuck with this issue and I need your kind help.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue on M2.4.1. Did you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands:

```
rm -r generated/*
rm -r var/page_cache/*
rm -r pub/static/*
composer install
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check the admin again if it has `Stores > Advanced > Developer` removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran the commands you told me but I still see Stores > Advanced > Developer.
Related folder was removed, composer install give : Nothing to install or update, and other bin/magento was successfully done.